# Is this code writing method recommended in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, statelesswidget

I installed [Awesome Flutter Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Nash.awesome-flutter-snippets) and [Flutter Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarufHassan.flutter-snippets) extension in VS Code. When I install these two extensions, I can use some keyboard shortcuts to generate widgets.

When I type `statelessW` or `stless` in the code and hit enter, it generates `StatelessWidget` like this:

`statelessW`:

```
class name extends StatelessWidget {
  const name({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

`stless`:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

You can see that the above two pieces of code are the same, the two pieces of code use `({super.key});` instead of `({Key? key}) : super(key: key);`.

Is it recommended to use `({super.key});` instead of `({Key? key}) : super(key: key);` in Flutter? I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is the new feature since Dart 2.17 - just a shorthand that achieves the same thing.

More details here: https://codewithandrea.com/tips/dart-2.17-super-initializers/

I'll just copy/paste an exmample from the link above:

Old syntax:

```
class Person {
  Person(this.name);
  final String name;
}

// Old way: before Dart 2.17
class Employee extends Person {
  Employee(String name, this.salary) : super(name);
  final int salary;
}
```

New syntax:

```
// New way: Dart 2.17 and above
class Employee extends Person {
  Employee(super.name, this.salary);
  final int salary;
}
```

Works for named arguments, too:

```
class Person {
  Person({required this.name});
  final String name;
}

// New way: Dart 2.17 and above
class Employee extends Person {
  Employee({required super.name, required this.salary});
  final int salary;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. While this link may answer the question, it's better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide a link for reference. Link-only answers may become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Good point, I edited my answer with details from the link.

Comment: Ok, I have accepted and upvoted this answer